PySpark connection to Cassandra returns "Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o54.start"
I'm try to make connection from Pyspark to Cassandra in virtual environment and the services is installed by docker. I've been using the --packages method to solve the dependencies but it seems doesn't work either.
i am using the the bash command to specify the jar files like this:
$ ./venv/bin/spark-submit \
  --master local[*] \
  --jars /opt/bitnami/spark/jars/spark-cassandra-connector_2.12-3.5.1.jar \
  --packages org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:3.5.1,org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.5.1 \
  --conf spark.cassandra.connection.host=cassandra \
  --conf spark.sql.extensions=com.datastax.spark.connector.CassandraSparkExtensions \
  /home/rama/project/randomuser/spark_stream.py`

I expect it can work properly to submit the job, but it appears that it still error. I assume this is still about the dependencies. the error appears like this
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o54.start.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/datastax/spark/connector/util/Logging

pyspark version 3.5.1
Scala version 2.12.18

When you supply the Spark Cassandra connector JAR, you will need supply all the other required JARs for the dependencies.
An easier way of using the connector is to use the Maven artifact with the --packages option so that all dependencies are included. In your case the command will look something like:
$ spark-submit \
  --master local[*] \
  --packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.12:3.5.1 \
  --packages org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:3.5.1,org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.5.1 \
  --conf spark.cassandra.connection.host=cassandra \
  --conf spark.sql.extensions=com.datastax.spark.connector.CassandraSparkExtensions \
  /home/rama/project/randomuser/spark_stream.py`

For details and examples, see the Spark Cassandra connector document on PySpark with Data Frames. Cheers!
